# In powershell, adding another set of values from a get-adcomputer result

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I've got a working script that gets the result from `Get-AdComputer` module:

```
Get-ADComputer -Filter 'operatingSystem -like "*Windows 10*"' -Properties *  | 
  Select -Property operatingSystem,operatingSystemVersion
```

Now I am trying to add another column that converts the value from `operatingSystemVersion` to another.

[image: sample result]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First create a [hashtable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_hash_tables) with your mapping:

```
$os = @{
  "10.0 (19042)" = "20H2"
  "10.0 (19043)" = "21H1"
}
```

Then you can use a [calculated property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_calculated_properties?view=powershell-7.2#select-object) that looks up the `operatingSystemVersion` in the hashtable:

```
Get-ADComputer -Filter 'operatingSystem -like "*Windows 10*"' -Properties *  | 
   Select -Property operatingSystem,operatingSystemVersion,
   @{N="Codename";E={$os[$_.operatingSystemVersion]}}
```

Comment: Awesome! appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Calculated Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_calculated_properties?view=powershell-7.2)

See an Example for the "NewColumn" Change the expression to what you need:

```
Get-ADComputer -Filter 'operatingSystem -like "*Windows 10*"' -Properties *  | 
Select -Property operatingSystem,operatingSystemVersion,
@{N="NewColumn";E={$_.operatingSystem.ToUpper()}}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Now I am trying to use the value from operatingSystemVersion to convert it to another value (1903, 1909, 20H2 or 21H1).